# MarkLogic LDAP - assigning an external name to a role not working

Tags: ldap, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using MarkLogic version 8.04 on CentOS 6. I am trying to do external authentication/authorization using LDAP.

I've created an external security authentication object:

```
name              ldap-config-simple
authentication    ldap
authorization     ldap
ldap server url   ldap://<my server address>:389
ldap base         ou=<mycompany>,dc=<info>,dc=<my org>
ldap attribute    sAMAccountName
ldap default user cn=<user id>,ou=xxxx,ou=yyyyy,dc=<info>,dc=<my org>
ldap bind method  simple
```

and associated it with an HTML App server (here are the pertinent settings):

```
authentication    basic
internal security true
external security ldap-config-simple
```

And I have associated an LDAP group to a role (here are the pertinent settings):

```
external name     cn=marklogic,ou=groups,dc=<info>,dc=<my org>
```

The problem is that authentication fails when I try to access the App server using my LDAP user. The log for the external LDAP server shows that the search string that MarkLogic sends looks like this:

```
(member=cn=marklogic,ou=groups,dc=<info>,dc=<my org>)
```

But the LDAP server is expecting the search to be:

```
(memberOf=cn=marklogic,ou=groups,dc=<info>,dc=<my org>)
```

The LDAP Server admin assures me that "memberOf" is the accepted standard for this type of query. We are using an OpenLDAP server - it is a pretty standard LDAP installation. Is there a way to have MarkLogic send "memberOf=" for the search rather than "member=" ?

Note that I was able to authenticate with my LDAP user ID through the App Server when I associated my user's DN in the LDAP server to a configured MarkLogic user. But I would prefer to use the Role based authentication since that puts the access controls in the LDAP server.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the question with your external authentication configuration?

Comment: @TylerReplogle I edited the question to add the external authentication configuration (not sure when you get notified ...)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. It is working now with the configuration above - although I didn't make any changes. MarkLogic support told me that a previous configuration may have been cached. In the process of debugging this I did a network packet trace to see exactly what MarkLogic was sending and it looks like it actually requests both the "memberOf" and "member" groups - I guess the LDAP admin only saw the latter in the logs.